# Regex include only one digit between chars

Tags: python, regex

I have to parse a PDF document and I'm using PyPDF2 with re(regex).

The file includes several lines like the one below:

```
18-02-202010:44:48PEDMILANO OVEST- BINASCOA1,40
```

I need to extract from this line the text( bold ) between the time  and the amount:

```
PEDMILANO OVEST- BINASCOA
```

The following code is working but sometimes this code doesn't find anything since can be a number between these chars, for example, `18-02-202010:44:48PEDMILANO OVE3ST- BINASCOA1,40`.

```
regex = re.compile(r'\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\D+\d+,\d\d')
```

Is there a way to include a number in this regular expression?

Comment: Where you have `\D+` change to `\D\S+` to allow more there.

Comment: Currently, there is only one unclear moment: what if your expected value ends with a number? What would be the rule to stop? I have dealt with the value that may start with a digit or any other char [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60952892/3832970), but currently, the number at the end of the string will prevent any trailing digits from capturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should simplify the current regex:

```
import re

s = '18-02-202010:44:48PEDMILANO OVE3ST- BINASCOA1,40'

re.search(r'\:\d+([A-Z].*?)(?=\d+\,\d+$)', s).group(1)
# 'PEDMILANO OVE3ST- BINASCOA'
```

---

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Twowhb/1)

- `\d+([A-Z].*?)(?=\d+\,\d+$)`

  - `\`: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
  - `\d+`: matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - 1st Capturing Group `([A-Z].*?)`
    Match a single character present in the list below `[A-Z]`

    - `A-Z` a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
    - `.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
    - `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
  - Positive Lookahead (?=\d+\,\d+$)
    Assert that the Regex below matches

    - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
    - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
      `\`, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
  - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
import re
text = "18-02-202010:44:48PEDMILANO OVEST- BINASCOA1,40"
print( re.sub(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{5,6}:\d{2}:\d{2}(.*?)\d+(?:,\d+)?$', r'\1', text) )
```

It can also be written as

```
re.sub(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{5,6}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\d+(?:,\d+)?$', '', text)
```

Or, if you prefer matching and capturing:

```
m = re.search(r'^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{5,6}:\d{2}:\d{2}(.*?)\d+(?:,\d+)?$', text)
if m:
    print( m.group(1) )
```

See an [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/Y7rCTw). With this solution, your data may start with any char, and will contain any char (excluding line break chars, since your data is on single lines).

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{5,6}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - datetime string: two digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, five or six digits, `:`, two  digits, `:` two  digits
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\d+(?:,\d+)?` - an int/float value pattern: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `,` and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bsW9Bi/1).